# How to do a for each from end of the array in PHP

Tags: php

## How to do a "for each" from the end of an array  in PHP ?

The end function can only return me one element http://php.net/manual/fr/function.end.php

Comment: Try `array_reverse` and loop it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the array and do a normal `foreach`?

```
$newArray = array_reverse($array);
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
   ...
}
```